# different results in safari and chrome

Tags: html, css

```
        .upper {
        color: crimson;
        line-height: 250%;
        word-spacing: -37px;
        font-family: Freight;
        font-size: 80px;
        font-weight: bold;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}


        .lower {
        color: crimson;
        line-height: 150%;
        word-spacing: -37px;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: -450px;
        font-family: Freight;
        font-size: 80px;
        font-weight: bold;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

this is my css code,
and this is my html code:

```
<span class="upper">EXAMPLE</span>
<span class="lower">Text</span>
```

but these two yield different results.
this is for Safari:

[image]

and this is for Chrome:

[image]

I would like both browsers to result in the Safari-like look, but I can't seem to see which part is the problem.

I am using github pages to host the website btw.

Answer (score 0):

still don't know why it works, but if i put a `<br>` between the html code it works. no idea why it works but it works.